# Font suggestions for album cover design

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I want to design an application about "Music" ( and "Album Cover" ), but I can't find sufficient font that has traditional feeling ( Similar to 1970-1980s Album covers ).

This is my basic design of the application but as you can see it doesn't have any 
***traditional feeling*** that I've mentioned. ( I've used "Cormorant Garamond" font for Headline, "Montserrat" and "Open Sans" for covers. )

[image]

I've searched in web for fonts got used in album covers and I find *"ITC Clearface"* , *"Gentium Basic"* , *"Taviraj"* and  *"Cormorant Garamond"* useful, but I am looking for something slightly different ! Something with a sense of **"Old jazz"** or **"Blues"** music.

***For example*** : 
[image]

What is your font suggestions about this project ? ( Preferably either from fonts.google.com or other free fonts )

Comment: Is it an application specifically dealing with retro album covers from the 70's and 80's or does it concern covers from all times?

Comment: This is quite a broad question, have you searched the web for fonts? Which ones have you found? Have you done a research on 70-80's aesthetics?

Comment: @Luciano I've made some changes.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend this - retro and groovy
http://typodermicfonts.com/mexcellence-in-broadcasting/

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.